# validate email address from an array of strings

Tags: c#, email, email-validation

I need to validate that email address is valid or not from **an array of strings as input**?

I am having the below code which works for **string emailID** but i need the same for **string[] emailID**. Thanks in Advance!!!

```
public static class EmailValidator
{
  const string EmailEx = @ "^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"

  private static ErrorDetail IsEmail(string input)
  {
    return !Regex.IsMatch(input, EmailEx)
        ? new ErrorDetail { Message = "Not a valid Email" }
        : null;
  }

  public static Func <string, ErrorDetail> ValidationMethod(string emailID)
  {
    return IsEmail;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be if there is more than one invalid email address?

Comment: @openshac I need to return Error Message "Not a valid Email" for each mail which is having invalid email address

Comment: So are you returning a single error message containing every email address, or an array of error messages (one for each email)? Have you tried using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `using System.Collections.Generic;` for following method to work.

```
public static class EmailValidator
    {
        const string EmailEx = @"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$";

        private static ErrorDetail IsEmail(string input)
        {
            return !Regex.IsMatch(input, EmailEx)
                ? new ErrorDetail { Message = "Not a valid Email" }
                : null;
        }

        public static Func<string, ErrorDetail> ValidationMethod(string emailID)
        {
            return IsEmail;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, ErrorDetail> AreEmailValid(string[] arrEmail)
        {
            Dictionary<string, ErrorDetail> invalidEmailDict = new Dictionary<string, ErrorDetail>();
            ErrorDetail errorDetail;

            foreach (string str in arrEmail)
            {
                errorDetail = IsEmail(str);
                if (errorDetail != null)
                {
                    invalidEmailDict.Add(str,errorDetail);
                }
            }

            return invalidEmailDict;
        }
    }
```